# How to change statusbar color in Fluent Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, statusbar, fluent-ribbon

I use Fluent Ribbon for my WPF application and I have stucked with simple thing. I can't change color of StatusBar (from FluentRibbon or default one).
My StatusBar is still BLUE. How can I change it? Background property doesn't work for me.

My XAML file looks like this (I removed all not needed code)

```
<Fluent:RibbonWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent" x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="App" Height="600" Width="960" Closing="Window_Closing" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke">
<Grid Name="grid" Focusable="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="250*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Fluent:Ribbon}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Fluent:StatusBar Foreground="White" Background="Red">


    </Fluent:StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I removed the tags from your question's title. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Answer (score 0):

The `StatusBar` in the `FluentRibbon` ignores the `Background` property, because id defines its own template that doesn't inherit this value but uses the theme colors.

If you want to change the background color of your status bar, you have to override the `DynamicResource` of the brush that is used as the background brush.

Here is an example:

```
<Fluent:StatusBar>
    <Fluent:StatusBar.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StatusBarInnerBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFB5C5D9" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Fluent:StatusBar.Resources>
</Fluent:StatusBar>
```

Comment: I copied your code into my application. It doesn't work for me. It's still blue

Comment: @Tatarinho, which version of `Fluent.Ribbon` are you using? Which theme?

Comment: I think it's 3.0.3.0 version.

Comment: @Tatarinho, okay, that might be the problem. My example is valid for the v4.x.

Comment: Where I can find newer version? I found only 3.0.3 on codeplex platform

Comment: I have changed runtime version to v4.0.30319, and it didn't change color. Is it really working on your machine?